# How do I treat a "SyntaxError" as an exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, syntax-error

I realize why "SyntaxError" is unskippable, but I would still like to know if there is a way around the syntax error anyway for purely educational purposes.

I want this code to run...

```
try:
    number = ((1)
    print(number)
except SyntaxError:
    print("ERROR")
```

...and get this output:

```
ERROR
# Program continues...
```

...but I get this instead...

```
number = ((1)
         ^
SyntaxError: '(' was never closed
```

and the program terminates.

Is there any possible way around this without fixing the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question, and I get that it is for educational purposes only.
Leaving the usefulness of having such a feature out of the table (because I think there's none of it), I'd consider the consequences of having this kind of syntax error handling.
It could lead to really severe bugs if used without care.

That is of course leaving the absolute lack of usefulness aside!

A try-catch block has never been a safety net for bad code (which syntax errors literally are: bad code), so, even without knowing if there's a workaround, I dare to say that there is no way such a thing could exist in any major programming language